# Increasing the hashmap value if the key already exists

Tags: java, hashmap, key, key-value, containskey

I am not sure why the value doesn't increase in my code when the code already exists. Any hint is really appreciated:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class MajorityElement {

    public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
        int halfSize = nums.length/2;
        int temp=0;
        int majorityValue=0;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (valuesMap.containsValue(nums[i])) {
                temp=valuesMap.get(nums[i]);
                valuesMap.put(nums[i], temp++);
            } else {
                valuesMap.put(nums[i], 1);
            }
        }
        for (Integer key : valuesMap.keySet()){
            if (valuesMap.get(key)>= halfSize){
                majorityValue=key;
            }
        }
        return majorityValue;

    }
    public static void main(String[] argc){
        MajorityElement majority=new MajorityElement();
        int[] sampleArray={1,4,6,8,8,9,8,8,0,8};
        int majorityRes=majority.majorityElement(sampleArray);
        System.out.println("majority value is = [" + majorityRes + "]");
        return;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I changed my code to

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (valuesMap.containsValue(nums[i])) {
             //   temp=valuesMap.get(nums[i]);
                valuesMap.put(nums[i], valuesMap.get(nums[i])+1);
            } else {
                valuesMap.put(nums[i], 1);
            }
        }
```

and still it prints 0 for `majorityRes`. Any idea why is that?

UPDATE': Fixed the problem by changing to `containsKey()` which was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
                valuesMap.put(nums[i], temp++);
```

When ++ is placed directly after the variable name, Java executes the command and then increments the variable by one. So, this line uses  the original value of "temp" to execute the command and *then* it increments by one.

What you want to do is increment the variable "temp" by one and *then* executing the command. In order to do this you need to put the ++ before the variable name like this:

```
                valuesMap.put(nums[i], ++temp);
```

That way Java knows to increment the variable by one and *then* execute the rest of the command.

Comment: I did the change you mentioned and my code still doesn't work!

Comment: what is the output @MonaJalal

Answer (score 1):

```
 temp=valuesMap.get(nums[i]);
 valuesMap.put(nums[i], temp++);
```

temp is being incrimented after the line so it is being placed into the map as the old value.

Change it to :

```
 temp=valuesMap.get(nums[i]);
temp++;
 valuesMap.put(nums[i], temp);
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing temp twice in your code? Doesn't make much sense!

Comment: Even in that case the code is not working. Please take a look at the update!